# loop on toggle on swiftUI

Tags: swift, for-loop, struct, syntax, swiftui

I'm beginner in swiftUI and i'd like to generate toggles from an array of a struct.

my struct :

```swift
struct Provider : Identifiable  {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var isOn:Bool 
}
```

and my view

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var providers:[Provider] = [Provider(id: 8, name: "Netflix", isOn: true), Provider(id: 564,name:"SALTO",isOn: false), Provider(id: 350, name: "Apple Tv Plus", isOn: false)]
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach (providers) {provider  in
                Toggle(isOn: .constant($provider.isOn), label: {
                Text("\(provider.name.capitalized)")
                })
           }
        }
    }   
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I don't know where to put de binding symbol.

- if I put this like this got an error : "Cannot find `$provider` in scope"
- if I put before isOn : "Value of type `Provider` has no member `$isOn`"
- if I put before providers in the ForEach : "Cannot convert value of type `Binding<[Provider]>` to expected argument type `Range<Int>`"

---

But If do:

```swift
VStack{
    Toggle(isOn: $providers[0].isOn, label: {
        Text("\(providers[0].name.capitalized)")
    })             
}
```

It's work as well !
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last example, you got the basics of it -- the simplest way to be able to modifier that `providers` array is to have an index to it. Here are two ways to achieve that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var providers:[Provider] = [Provider(id: 8, name: "Netflix", isOn: true), Provider(id: 564,name:"SALTO",isOn: false), Provider(id: 350, name: "Apple Tv Plus", isOn: false)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(providers.indices) { providerIndex  in
                Toggle(isOn: $providers[providerIndex].isOn) {
                    Text("\(providers[providerIndex].name.capitalized)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var providers:[Provider] = [Provider(id: 8, name: "Netflix", isOn: true), Provider(id: 564,name:"SALTO",isOn: false), Provider(id: 350, name: "Apple Tv Plus", isOn: false)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(providers.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,provider)  in
                Toggle(isOn: $providers[index].isOn) {
                    Text("\(provider.name.capitalized)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second is my preferred way, since you get the `provider` as one of the parameters. There are slight performance issues with huge collections, at which point you might want to explore `indexed` from [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms).

Comment: Great -- you can mark the answer as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark